# Jquery simple load() test into a container div not working

Tags: jquery, html, load

I'm new to jquery and having a problem getting an html doc to load into a container div using jquery's load() function.

I'm running this test with both htmls files living on an external web server within the same base-level html folder.

I wrote an alert into the click function presenting the load(), to test to see if the browser is recognizing the js function, and the alert pops up just fine in both FF and Chrome, but the html doc never loads.

I appreciate any help you can provide. Hopefully this is just me missing something horribly obvious.

Thanks!

**The base html file with the container div (bindtestone.html):**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("li#loader").click(function() {
        $("#container").load("bindtesttwo.html").fadeIn("fast");
        alert("this link is working");
    });
  });   

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #loaderdiv { width:300px; border:1px solid #000;
     position:relative; }

    #container { width:500px; height:400px; border:1px solid #000;
     position:relative; overflow:visible; }

    #dynacontent { width:100px; border:solid 1px #000; 
     position:relative;  }
</style>    

</head>

<body>

<div id="loaderdiv">
  <ul><li id="loader"><a href="">load file</a></li></ul>
</div>

<div id="container">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The second html file I'm trying to load using jquery (bindtesttwo.html):**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="dynacontent">
    <a href="">This is a link</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console to see if you're getting data back or errors?

Comment: I did before posting,and just did again, with the changes suggested below. Consoles in FF and Chrome aren't throwing errors, nor alerting me to any missing elements.

Comment: Im pretty certain that link you have in there is causing your page to reload :) ... the link in the `li` that is

Answer (score 0):

Your blind test 2 should only have the div that represents the content in it... try that.

get rid of the `<a href>` tag

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried that, and nothing loads in Chrome.

Comment: But in FF, I see my content from bindtest 2 for just a moment, and then it disappears. Maybe a css thing?

Comment: gimme a sec lemme take a harder look at it

Comment: oh lol you need to do a prevent default on that link or perhaps adding a pound sign might work on the 'href' piece.... honestly get rid of the link and fire the click off the li... the link is causing the page to reload

Comment: You rock, thanks so  much! I knew I missing something obvious.

Comment: can you rate my answer please? so that the question can be "answered"?